# Why devise use sometimes flash[:alert] and sometimes resource.errors.error_messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

To output error messages, devise uses both flash[:alert] and resource.errors.error_messages.

Why is just using flash[:alert] not enough?
Any benefit by using them separately?

Some error messages like "Invalid email or password." are in flash[:alert] not in resource.errors.error_messages. But I believe it's really related to resource object.

I always do like this

`flash[:alert] = flash[:alert].to_a.concat resource.errors.full_messages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails Flash is often used to display some message, that describes situation in general.
From the other side, resource.errors contains errors, for specific fields.

For example, flash can contain: "Invalid email or password"
And email field will have following error: "Such email already exists".

Devise is one of gems, that follow such convention.